# Are there any alternative time and date applets for Gnome Panel?

Tags: indicator, applet

The default time and date applet for Gnome Panel (in Gnome Classic) is buggy and leaks memory. Are there any alternatives I can download? I'm looking for something that will display the current date and time, and ideally have options for displaying other time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be no alternatives to the default time and date applet for having a clock in the Gnome-Panel.

However, I have been able to get useful time displays using [Screenlets](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Screenlets?content=73346). They are not perfect in that they can overlap with windows. However, they will suffice until the time and date applet bugs are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Is gworldclock from the softwarecenter something worth installing ?

It has a plugin for different time-zones.

I found some other packages in the softwarecenter, but they're mostly used for system administration (maybe good enough for you, this I don't know)

Searching in the get-deb site didn't give me something valuable.

I know there are some beautifull widgets (e.g. Webup8 and OMG ubuntu (sites)) in HTC-style, but I'm not shure that is something you were looking for.

I hope this leads you a bit further.